# Search webpage for http URLs using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How would search a webpage for http links? When a page is using HTTPS, I'd like to find all links to insecure content. I thought about using `indexOf` or `regex` but cannot seem to come up with how I could search the whole page.

I have also tried `document.getElementsByTagName` with no luck.

Comment: When you say webpage is URL? let me clarify, you are looking to parse html content trying to get all href="" right?

Comment: not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get the url of the current webpage? Or for a given webpage, are you trying to get the URLs of the links on the page?

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear. My goal is to search for any non-secure content within a secure page. Any references to http such as scripts, images, links, etc

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: Its a project of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could use `document.querySelectorAll` and find all elements with attributes `src` and `href` that start with http:// like so:

```
var insecure_content = document.querySelectorAll('[src^="http://"],[href^="http://"]');
```